# How to make axWindowsMediaPlayer run on separate thread?

Tags: vb.net, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am using axWindowsMediaPlayer that loops through videos and pictures. One thing that I notice is whenever the transition between videos to pictures occurs my application hangs, this is the case for deployment PC. In my development PC nothing like that happens.

This is my settings for `axWindowsMediaPlayer1`

```
        With .AxWindowsMediaPlayer1
            .settings.setMode("loop", True)
            'Mutes the media player
            .settings.volume = 0
            .uiMode = "none"
            .Ctlenabled = False
            .stretchToFit = True
        End With
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "my system hangs"?  That makes it sound like your entire PC stops doing anything else at that time.  If that's the case then how could using a different thread help?  If that's not what happens then maybe you should use words that indicate what actually does happen.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah you are right. What I mean is my application hangs up.

Comment: In order for a control to execute on a secondary thread, it must be created on a secondary thread. That means that the form it's on must be created on a secondary thread.  There's no inherent issue doing that but it also means that any other controls on that same form will belong to that thread too.  The form can also not be modal to any other form on the main thread.  If neither of those conditions is an issue for you, go ahead and start a new thread and then create a form containing your control and show it.

Comment: Ohh, it seems that I willl need to re-create my project because I depend a lot on the UI thread. Thanks @jmcilhinney, I'll get back to that project someday.